# handling scheduled/time bound tasks in enterprise web application

Tags: php, web-applications, cron, scheduled-tasks, domain-driven-design

On the surface it looks very simple problem that I am facing. In an enterprise web app (LAMP stack) we need to add some time based & schedule based tasks. Some examples are

- when a user logs in and has stayed active for more than 30 minutes, send them a lucky coupon.
- send a newsletter to subscribers every Monday. [easily handled by a cron job]
- If a user does not login for 3 days, start stalking her. [doable by cron job but ...]
- deduct phone bill amount from user account on 1st working day of every month at 9.
- repeat failed deduction every subsequent work day at 9 for a max of 15 retries.

I hope that give you an idea of what is going on that needs to be handled.

At the moment we have cron jobs of almost every possible situation and they are kind of working but as you can see with the above scenarios, we are forced to run those crons almost every second (bit exaggeration but almost).

To handle the issue more elegantly and better implement the ddd concepts, we are thinking to make clock ticking as first class citizen of the application.

We would like to make a simple central clock ticker class, that will emit ticks as time events every second.

The ticks will be published to the central event bus.

And all the classes that are interested to act on the tick, will subscribe to the event bus.

What I am unable to figure out yet is that this will result in making a lot of subscriber/registrant classes code to run on every tick. As this is already the case with cron, could there be a better way to handle the subscription part so that a specific subscription is notified only when it needs to be notified?

And before we even get into solving this problem the way I am proposing, is there is a better way to handle this kind of problems? The key point in this whole scenario seems to be how to trigger something X based on how much time has passed since something Y happened in the domain. I believe I am not the first one to face this issue and this problem must have been long solved already but I am unable to stumble upon any road sign pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The way I have handled this in the past is to queue commands as soon as I know something should happen and then the scheduler will fire off the commands when the time has come.

The scheduler is simply a process that runs as a service and wakes every N milliseconds to find any commands that have passed their ScheduledTime.

For example:

- The user has logged in. Queue a command for 30 minutes hence to give them a coupon. After 30 minutes, the scheduler will send the command. If the session is still active, then the command is accepted and a coupon is presented. Otherwise, it simply does nothing.

You also mention several examples that are best handled by a traditional scheduler (cron as you mentioned) and will fire off a batch command. Depending on how knowledgeable your domain is about things like newsletters, you would either issue individual commands to your domain objects or simply pull a report and run a job to send emails.

If you do handle these types of processes in your domain, then your domain should also queue the next command. A saga or process manager would be most suitable for this type of operation. E.g.

```
CreateNewsletter (This is the batch) -> NewsletterCreated
    Accounts.Each(SendAccountNewsletter) -> AccountNewsletterSent
        NewsletterCompleted (This is the batch) -> 
            Queue(command: CreateNewsletter, when: NextMondayAt9) (This is the next batch)
```

Hope that helps.

**P.S.** If you publish ticks on your bus, you will have a ton of noise to filter through.